# Javascript createElement, modify output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I downloaded a livesearch JavaScript plugin for my site, it's working, but I need help to modify it a little bit.

Here is the code:

```
    $.ajax({url: $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search/ajax&keyword=' + keywords, dataType: 'json', type: 'GET', success: function(result) {
    if( result.length > 0 ) {
        var eList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
        eList.id = 'livesearch_search_results';
        var eListElem;
        var eLink;
        var eHref;
        for( var i in result ) {
            eListElem = document.createElement( 'li' );
            eLink = document.createElement( 'a' );
            if( result[i].img != null ) {
                var eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
                eImg.className = "img_container";
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = result[i].img;
                eImg.appendChild( img );
            }
            else {
                eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
                eImg.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            }
            eDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
            eLink.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].name) );
            if( typeof(result[i].href) != 'undefined' ) {
                eHref = result[i].href;
            }
            else {
                eHref = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + result[i].product_id + '&keyword=' + keywords;
            }
            eLink.href = eHref;
            eDiv.appendChild( eLink );
            eDiv.innerHTML = eDiv.innerHTML + result[i].desc;
            eListElem.appendChild( eImg );
            eListElem.appendChild( eDiv );
            eListElem.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
            eListElem.setAttribute( 'rel', eHref );
            $(eListElem).bind('click', function(){
                var gto = $(this).attr( 'rel' );
                try {
                    if( gto != false && gto.length > 0 ) {
                        document.location = gto;
                    }
                }
                catch( e ) {}
            });
            eList.appendChild( eListElem );
        }
        if( $('#livesearch_search_results').length > 0 ) {
            $('#livesearch_search_results').remove();
        }
        $('#search_menu').append(eList);
    }
}});
```

The output is something like this (without `<ul>`):

```
  <li rel="http://url">
  <span class="img_container">
    <img src="http://url.jp">
  </span>
  <div>
    <a href="http://url">MONS 1.0 (CTM 2013)</a>
    Description...</div>
  <br>
  </li>
```

Is there any way to modify output to this:

```
  <li rel="http://url">
  <a href="http://url">           <---- <a> tag here
  <span class="img_container">
    <img src="http://url.jp">
  </span>
  <span class="product-container">    <------ <span> tag here
    <span class="title">MONS 1.0 (CTM 2013)</span> <------ <span> tag here, remove <a> tag
    <span class="description">Description...</span> <------ <span> tag here
  </div>
  </a>
  </li>
```

This is beyond my JS knowledge.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you could do it but it's not likely to have the effect you are after, `DIV` elements are [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) while `A` elements are not. Also why do you want o add a `BR` to the end of a `LI`, just use CSS to pad it

Comment: @JasonSperske I want the whole <li> clickable, <a> should be display: block; BR is from the original code, I removed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the severe disclaimer that this is untested, I'd say *yes*!

The code is neatly divided up, makes it easy to read, let's keep in that spirit.

Towards the top we see the following:

```
var eList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
eList.id = 'livesearch_search_results';
var eListElem;
var eLink;
var eHref;
```

These variables are declared but not defined.  They will be used over and over again to build each `<li>`.  We're moving the link (`eLink`) so we can leave that, but we're also changing a `<div>` to a `<span>`, as well as adding several other elements; namely product container, title, and description.  Let's pop in some variables for those, while we're here (the original author appears to have not defined `eDiv` up here, we'll be replacing that with `ePCont`, anyway):

```
var eList = document.createElement( 'ul' );
eList.id = 'livesearch_search_results';
var eListElem;
var eLink;
var eHref;
var ePCont, eTitle, eDesc;
```

The next step is two-fold.

First we see a bunch of `document.createElement`s (some in if-statements, some not).  `document.createElement` makes a new DOM element of the specified type.  It does *not* add the element to the document, it only builds an instance of it, so it doesn't matter what order they're created in.  This brings us to part two:  `[element].appendChild([element])` places one element in the tree under another.  If an element in that tree belongs to the document, it will be displayed.  This means first we'll create a series of objects, then add them to each other, and finally add the topmost element to the document.

We're going to drastically rewrite large parts of this code, but the first part (up through where the images are created) is just fine:

```
        eListElem = document.createElement( 'li' );
        eLink = document.createElement( 'a' );
        if( result[i].img != null ) {
            var eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
            eImg.className = "img_container";
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = result[i].img;
            eImg.appendChild( img );
        }
        else {
            eImg = document.createElement( 'span' );
            eImg.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }
```

The next line defines the container div that we now call `ePCont`, let's rewrite it appropriately (and give it a class):

```
ePCont = document.createElement( 'span' );
ePCont.className = "product-container";
```

The line after THAT puts some text in the link.  We're putting an element in it instead, so we can safely remove it, but the if statement *after* that (which makes sure we're going to be using a kosher url) stays:

```
        if( typeof(result[i].href) != 'undefined' ) {
            eHref = result[i].href;
        }
        else {
            eHref = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + result[i].product_id + '&keyword=' + keywords;
        }
        eLink.href = eHref;
```

Finally, let's create our two new spans:

```
eTitle = document.createElement( 'span' );
eDesc = document.createElement( 'span' );
```

and populate them:

```
eTitle.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].name) );
eDesc.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].desc) );
```

and set their classes:

```
ePCont.className = "title";
ePCont.className = "description";
```

Now it's time to append everything to everything else.  We'll start from the lowest elements, and work our way upwards.

```
ePCont.appendChild(eTitle);
ePCont.appendChild(eDesc);
eLink.appendChild(eImg);
eLink.appendChild(ePCont);
eListElem.appendChild(eLink);
```

The rest of the document should flow more or less as it did:

```
    eListElem.setAttribute( 'rel', eHref );
    $(eListElem).bind('click', function(){
        var gto = $(this).attr( 'rel' );
        try {
            if( gto != false && gto.length > 0 ) {
                document.location = gto;
            }
        }
        catch( e ) {}
    });
    eList.appendChild( eListElem );

    ...
```

Again, totally untested, but I hope my description will give you enough knowledge of the workings of this plug-in to trouble shoot it!

Comment: Yess, thank you for the detailed insctruction. It's clear now. I think you made a little typo here: ePCont .className = "title";
ePCont .className = "description"; ---> it's should be eTitle.className = "live-title"; eDesc.className = "live-description";  again, thank you very much.

Comment: According to your original specs, the class names are "title" and "description", but it's clear you're well on your way to know exactly what you need!  Feel free to ask any other questions you may have!

Comment: One more question: If I want to create a div after </li> (eList.appendChild( eListElem ); - if I am correct), then this code why don't work? 

var tRiangle;
tRiangle = document.createElement( 'div' );
tRiangle.className = "triangle";
tRiangle.appendChild(tRiangle);

Comment: ha, you're adding `tRiangle` to itself.  What you want to do is `eList.appendChild(tRiangle)`.

Comment: Sorry I said wrong. I just want one <div> before </ul>. With eList.appendChild I got <div>'s after every <li>

Comment: Do you want one `<div>` per `<li>`? Or just one, regardless of the number of `<li>`s?

Comment: You should know that that's not kosher with any current HTML standards.  Only `<li>`s should appear directly inside of `<ul>`s, consider putting it after the `<ul>`, instead.  Having said that, to do this put the `eList.appendChild(tRiangle)` AFTER the loop.

Comment: You are totally right, what If <ul> was in a div like this? http://d.pr/i/wbKR+ but how should I do this?

Comment: You're going to want to use jQuery to retrieve the `div` by id, you're also going to want to give that div an id.  An id is similar to class (it can be used to style, for example) but must be unique.  No two elements should have the same id.  We CAN however use the class name as an id (`<div class = "live-search" id = "live-search"`>).  Now we just use jQuery: `$("#live-search").append(tRiangle)` (the # tells jQuery we're using an id, `append()` is jQuery's version of `appendChild()`).

Comment: I am close to success. :) I created a div for <ul>, with style display: none, when there is a search then it is displayed. I am just having trouble with the triangle div. http://d.pr/i/Qjdi+ the triangle div is generated 3x, but why? The code before var eList = document.createElement('ul'); is :      var tRian = document.createElement( 'div' ); 
   tRian.className = "triangle";
   $('#search-results').append(tRian);

Comment: Do me a favor and add your current version of the code to the end of your post so I can see it more clearly.